# Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю почему код не работает...все вроде сделал правильно но выходит ошибка в консоли когда и API ключ  нормальный  код города тоже:
https://codepen.io/serghei7/pen/mdMxajK

```js
const param = {
    "url": "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/",
    "appid": "2cdb83734e4ed8fc7926b97946f03da4"
}


function getWeather() {
    const cityId = document.querySelector('.city_1').value;



    fetch(`${param.url}weather?id=${cityId}&units=metric&APPID=${param.appid}`)
        .then(function (resp) { return resp.json() })
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            document.querySelector('.package-name').textContent = data.name;
            document.querySelector('.price').innerHTML = Math.round(data.main.temp - 273) + '&deg;';
            document.querySelector('.disclaimer').textContent = data.weather[0]['description'];
            document.querySelector('.disc').innerHTML = (data.main.humidity) + '%';
            document.querySelector('.features li').innerHTML = `<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${data.weather[0]['icon']}@2x.png">`;
        });
}

document.querySelector('#city').onchange = getWeather;

function createSelect() {
    let divElem = document.getElementById("city");

    let selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.setAttribute("class", "city_1");
    divElem.appendChild(selectList);

    const cities = {
        0: "Select City",
        23232: "London",
        33456: "Minsk",
        703446: "Kyiv",
        3084826: "Gdansk"
    }

    let myArray = [];

    for (let key in cities) {
        var optionList = document.createElement("option");
        optionList.setAttribute("value", key);
        myArray = cities[key];
        optionList.textContent = myArray;
        selectList.appendChild(optionList);

    }


}


document.querySelector('.g-button').onclick = createSelect;
```

```css
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.g-button {
    margin-left: 15px;
    border: solid 2px #4caf50;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.city_1 {
    margin-left: 15px;
    border: solid 2px #4caf50;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/mustard-ui@latest/dist/css/mustard-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">



        <div id="city">
            <button class="g-button">Generate City</button>
        </div>

        <div class="pricing-table row">
            <div class="package featured">
                <p class="package-name">City</p>
                <hr>
                <p class="price">Degrees </p>
                <p class="disclaimer">Clouds</p>
                <hr>
                <p>Humidity</p>
                <p class="disc"></p>
                <hr>
                <ul class="features">
                    <li>SKY</li>
                </ul>
                <button class="button-primary">Go</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Может все таки city id неверно указан?

Comment: попробуйте id для London 2643743,а для Kyiv 703448

Comment: для Minsk 625144

Comment: Вы правы...все заработало...спасибо большое...Странно то что я коды городов взял с официального сайта

Answer (score 1):

А вы проверьте коды городов, указанные вами коды не найдены, а вот код `2172797` работает и по запросу

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&units=metric&APPID=2cdb83734e4ed8fc7926b97946f03da4
```

и выдаёт

```
{"coord":{"lon":145.7667,"lat":-16.9167},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":25.52,"feels_like":26.32,"temp_min":25.04,"temp_max":25.97,"pressure":1009,"humidity":84},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":0.51,"deg":210},"clouds":{"all":40},"dt":1636287104,"sys":{"type":1,"id":9490,"country":"AU","sunrise":1636227401,"sunset":1636273472},"timezone":36000,"id":2172797,"name":"Cairns","cod":200}
```

сам js код в порядке (конечно есть где улучшить, но он работоспособен)

Comment: .все заработало...спасибо большое...